# Get back list of string from an stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have an stream that contains Strings and list of Strings and I want to get out all values as List of Strings.
Anyway to do this with some stream operation ?

```
Stream stream = Stream.of("v1", Arrays.asList("v2, v3"));
```

Comment: Where's the stream here?

Comment: What do you mean when you say stream over? What do you want to get?

Comment: Why don't you use `l.addAll(Arrays.asList("v2","v3"))`, and type `l ` as a `List<String>`?

Comment: ***I have an list that contains Strings***.... no you dont....

Comment: this is little bit simplified, I get an stream with this mixed types

Comment: Do you have control when elements (either single or lists) are added to the list?

Comment: nope parse do that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally you don't mix up such different types in a list, but you can get the result you want from this; each single string can be converted to a stream of one string, and each list of strings can be converted to a stream of multiple strings; then `flatMap` will flatten all the streams to one single stream of strings.

```
List<String> strings = l.stream()
        .flatMap(o -> {
                if (o instanceof List) {
                    return ((List<String>) o).stream();
                }
                return Stream.of((String) o);
            })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You'll get an `unchecked cast` warning, but that's what you get for mixing up different types in one container.

Comment: You can remove the warning by adding a `if (o instanceof String)` no?

Comment: @Nathan No, the warning is from casting to `(List<String>)`, because Java won't be able to verify the generic type. An `instanceof` will have no effect.

Comment: ok this was my solution, wanted to now if I can skip the instanceof  in some way

Comment: @poyger The way to avoid the `instanceof` is to not mix different types of object inside one container. As long as they're mixed up, you'll need something like `instanceof` to separate them.

Comment: @poyger if that was your solution, you should have included it in the question!

Comment: You [can get rid of the “unchecked” warning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44889287/2711488), but *of course*, there’s no way to get rid of the `instanceof`…

Comment: collect hear return Object, needed to cast it to List<String>, do you understand why ?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid “unchecked” warnings, you have to cast each element, which works best when you perform it as a subsequent per-element operation, after the `flatMap` step, when the single `String` elements and `List` instances are already treated uniformly:

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("v1");
list.add(Arrays.asList("v2","v3"));

List<String> strings = list.stream()
    .flatMap(o -> o instanceof List? ((List<?>)o).stream(): Stream.of(o))
    .map(String.class::cast)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But, as already said by others, not having such a mixed type list in the first place, is the better option.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a stream over a list of Objects, then do something depending of the nature of the object. To do this, you could use [Khelwood's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44888577/5372723). But you're very probably better using something like:

```
List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
l.add("v1");
l.addAll(Arrays.asList("v2","v3"));
```